# Changing the Classloader JRuby uses in a block

Tags: jruby, classloader

I want to directly integrate with JRuby so a block can be called within a child ClassLoader.

The goal is for list of Jars to be passed to a [custom ClassLoader](https://github.com/mguymon/naether/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tobedevoured/naether/PathClassLoader.java) to load for the execution of the block. The problem I have is telling the JRuby runtime to use the new ClassLoader instead of the default.  What I have now is a bit of a hack, it manually calls `create(string class)` for constructing an instance using the custom ClassLoader.

For this [Ruby](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/class_loader/lib/lock_jar/class_loader.rb), which uses [LockJar](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar) to get a list of Jars from the file `tmp/IsolateJarfile.lock`, an [example](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/class_loader/spec/lock_jar/class_loader_spec.rb) of how it is used:

```
email = LockJar::ClassLoader.new( 'tmp/IsolateJarfile.lock' ).isolate do
    email = new_instance( 'org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail' )
    email.setSubject( 'test subject' )
    email
end

email.getSubject().should eql 'test subject'
```

This works, the SimpleEmail is created in the child ClassLoader. The default JRuby classpath is not changed. The call to `new_instance( 'org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail' )` is ugly. Ideally `org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail.new` could be called and the JRuby runtime would pull from the custom class loader instead of the default JRuby classloader. I tried changing `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader` during the block execution, but that did not work. I snooped around the JRuby source some, but could not figure out a good way to hook into the ClassLoader.